# How to add path to file in Java args

Tags: java, command-line, jar, args

i am working on one project and i come to the problem.
I need to run .jar over cmnd prompt and i need to put path to .properties file into the argument, for example:

```
java -jar myproject.jar C:\path\to\config.properties
```

Now i have a path to file satatic

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("config\\crdb.properties");
```

And i need to somehow put variable instead of static path and change it with argument.

Thank you.

Comment: that's what args[] in your main function is for

Answer (score 1):

use -D to put your **System variable** and use System.getProperty to get it :

```
  java -Dpath.properties=C:\path\to\config.properties -jar myproject.jar
```

---

```
String pathProp= System.getProperty("path.properties");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathProp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `args` array:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0])) {
     // do stuff..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading the property file from main method you can simply access command line arguments via `args[]` array `public static void main(String args[])` simple code like below might do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String splitChar="=";

    try {

        Map<String, String> propertyList = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(args[0]))
                .stream()
                .map(String.class::cast)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(line -> line.split(splitChar)[0],
                        line -> line.split(splitChar)[1]));
        System.out.println(propertyList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

or else you can pass the path as `vm option`

> java -Dfile.path={path to config file} {JavaClassFile to execute}

and you can get the path like below (from any where in your code)

```
System.getProperty("file.path")
```

and same as in main method above you can read the property file and put it into a `HashMap` which I prefer